# Cannot perform explicit cast

Tags: c#, generics, activator

Can you clarify me why in this piece of code:

```
private Dictionary<Type, Type> viewTypeMap = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();

public void ShowView<TView>(ViewModelBase viewModel, bool showDialog = false)
    where TView : IView
{
    var view = Activator.CreateInstance(viewTypeMap[typeof(TView)]);
    (IView)view.ShowDialog();
}
```

I get the error:

> "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object
>   expressions can be used as a statement."

IView defines the ShowDialog() method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The cast operator is of lower precedence than the member access operator.

```
(A)B.C();
```

is parsed as

```
(A)(B.C());
```

which is not a legal statement. You ought to write

```
((A)B).C();
```

if you mean to cast `B` to `A` and then call `C()` on type `A`.

For your future reference, the precedence table is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Why not try the following so that your view object is declared as IView instead of object?

```
public void ShowView<TView>(ViewModelBase viewModel, bool showDialog = false) where TView : IView
{
    var view = (IView)Activator.CreateInstance(viewTypeMap[typeof(TView)]);
    view.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast it as it is being instantiated, then if it is used multiple times you won't need to recast it every time.

```
var view = (IView)Activator.CreateInstance(viewTypeMap[typeof(TView)]);
view.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
(IView)view.ShowDialog();
```

to

`((IView) view).ShowDialog();`

Eric explained why